# I have a FAB anchored to a bottom bar that have a bugged behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I developing an Android App that has an `Activity` that have a `bottomBar` with a `Floating Action Button` anchored.
The way I did it was like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabNewIssue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/strong_blue"
        android:contentDescription="Add Issue"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_add_24"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:fabCustomSize="60dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

What I do next is, in certain fragments, I need to hide the `BottomBar` and the `FAB`, and the way I do it is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as MainActivity).let {
            it.toolbarText = "Olá " + it.user?.name
            it.appbar.setExpanded(true)
            it.binding.fabNewIssue.visibility = View.GONE
            it.binding.bottomBar.visibility = View.GONE
            it.binding.mainFragmentContainer.setPadding(0,0,0, 
                      Utils().convertDpToPixel(60f,requireContext()).toInt())
        }
    }
```

I have no problem with this behavior, my problem comes when I try to navigate back and show the `BottomBar` and `FAB` again. A bug happens and the rounded bar effect disappears as shown:

[First Fragment with normal Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD4q4.png)

[Second Fragment with hidden Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlhDa.png)

[First Fragment with bugged Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Df8.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to nest your bottom bar and FAB in a container and hide/show that layout instead.

XML layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabNewIssue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/strong_blue"
            android:contentDescription="Add Issue"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_add_24"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            app:fabCustomSize="60dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomBar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    (activity as MainActivity).let {
        it.toolbarText = "Olá " + it.user?.name
        it.appbar.setExpanded(true)
        it.binding.bottomBarContainer.visibility = View.GONE
        it.binding.mainFragmentContainer.setPadding(0,0,0, 
                  Utils().convertDpToPixel(60f,requireContext()).toInt())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested your suggestion and it worked with minor tweaks. Had to change from FrameLayout to CoordinatorLayout because the FAB to work with the BottomBar really needs a CoordinatorLayout. And had to set an height to the CoordinatorLayout, because if it was set to wrap_content, I don't know why, but it would only wrap the bottomBar and the FAB would get cut.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to match the suggested solution.